# Putting chrome.tabs.query in a function always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension that makes a lot of use of getting the id of the current active tab in the current active window. Using chrome.tabs.query wrapped around a lof of logic makes my code messy, but putting it in it's own function to return the current tab always returns undefined - why?

```
function _getCurrentTab(){
    var theTab;
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow:true},function(tab){
        theTab = tab;
    });
    return theTab;
};
console.log(_getCurrentTab());
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chrome.tabs.query` is asynchronous, so your return executes before the `theTab = tab` in the callback or the callback itself is executed, So try:

```
function _getCurrentTab(callback){ //Take a callback
    var theTab;
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow:true},function(tab){
        callback(tab); //call the callback with argument
    });
};

_displayTab(tab){ //define your callback function
    console.log(tab);
 };

 _getCurrentTab(_displayTab); //invoke the function with the callback function reference
```

Comment: @tripRev This is the way you handle callbacks, if you are getting undefoned still just put a console.log(tab) inside your chrome.tabs.query callback itself and it will be undefined, because something else is wrong.

Comment: revisiting this after 3 years I can see you were absolutely correct. If you want a func which returns the current tab, you can't use the result straight away, you need to provide a cbfunc which uses it when it's done.